# Hosting MEAN stack app on VPS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I created one web application based on the MEAN stack. The front-end and back-end of the application are in different folders. So how I can host this application?

Comment: Where you serve the front end, you need to pass the correct path to that folder in your back end code. You've not given much details though so your question need more work before you get a definitive answer.

Comment: do you know how to host them alone?

Comment: Yes its working fine on local server

Answer (score -1):

If it is windows server,
You can either host using IIS or any other hosting servers.

If it is Linux I will recommend going with nginx server simple put the location of your folder in nginx configuration.

And for the backed part use PM2 module for nodejs.

Comment: PM2 is node module and you can either create a node route and redirect to the public folder or app folder for index.html I suggested you if you have different folder please think while down vote

Comment: There is no mention about IIS or nginx servers. `MEAN` = Mongo, Express, Angular and Node. Node for backend server. That means IIS/nginx is not in the question as it's part of completely different architecture. PM2 is quite hefty nonetheless just for routing and OP problem can be solved using plain JS without big dependencies but that has to be clarified by OP as his question is not clear enough.